# TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'EXTERNAL_RESOURCES.items()'

Tags: python-3.x, веб-программирование, шаблоны, jinja2

When i go to the page it raises `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'EXTERNAL_RESOURCES.items()'`

But if i try to remove the '()' just {% for name,link in EXTERNAL_RESOURCES.items %} there is nothing on the page (it's blank).

**In external_resources.html:**

```
{% for name,link in EXTERNAL_RESOURCES.items() %}
    <li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

**In views.py:**

```
EXTERNAL_RESOURCES= {
    'Wiki': 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/',
    'StackOverflow': 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/',
    'Stepik': 'https://stepik.org/'
}

def external_resources(request):
    return render(request, 'mainapp/external_resources.html', context=EXTERNAL_RESOURCES)
```

**In urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('ext-resources/', external_resources, name='ext_resources')
]
```

I am a nube in web so I'm glad to any of your remarks:)

Comment: `{% for name,link in resources | items %}` а так?

Comment: Кст, в шаблон ведь передается `context=EXTERNAL_RESOURCES`, т.е. в нем нужно с `context` работать, не?

Comment: описался, в исходнике EXTERNAL_RESOURCES

Comment: | items такого фильтра вроде нет

Comment: А у вас именно jinja2 или django? Погуглил и у них есть схожесть, но некоторые различия, т.е. в django не нужно будет вызывать функцию, т.е. просто `.items`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8018989/5909792

Comment: django с инсталлированной jinja2

Comment: Не думаю, что jinja2 там выполняется, тем более ошибка `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError` как бы говорит, что генерировал шаблон :)

Comment: а как сделать чтобы она выполнялась? в пайчарме отображается как инсталлированная

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30715508/5909792 см в `Then modify your TEMPLATES list in the settings.py to contain the jinja2 BACKEND :`